# Flow Using more than Object

Tags: visual-workflow, governorlimits, loop

Trying to build a flow that used GET RECORD to pull a filtered list of Opportunities, and use the AccountIds from these Opportunities to update a list of Accounts.

The only way I have achieved that is by pulling a collection of opportunities, looping through every opp and getting the Account where Accountid = Opp.Accountid and updating the record.

**The issue with this method** is that I have a GET RECORDS inside my loop which causes me to exceed my allowed SOQL queries.

Please advise / is there a better method instead of a flow to approach this.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You can loop over the collection of opps and use an assignment in the loop to build a sobject collection of accounts to update.  Then you can do one update record to update all accounts.

Comment: you should use [edit] and post a screen shot of your flow

Comment: Hi Gorav, thank you for taking the time to respond. 

I currently only have the AccountID from the Opportunity Get Records. How do I  use that (Opportunity.AccountID) along with an Assignment logic to create an Account collection of that I can use to update after the loop is over without doing an Account Get Records inside the loop?

In other words, how do I get the single account record using the opp.accountid that I can then modify and add in a collection of accounts all inside the loop?

edit: I feel like I am missing a step before my loop decision